# Can't get Intel heatsink back on

Tags: cpu, cooling, desktop-computer, intel-core-i5, heatsink

I took off the `CPU heat sink` to blow out the dust. Now I can't get it back on. I've tried everything I read from Google: I pull up the black pins so they're inside the white part before putting the heat sink in place, and then push firmly down. Usually, 2 of the 4 pins don't make a clicking noise. Is it possible the pins are broken? I need this computer for work so would buying a new heat sink solve the problem? Here are some pictures. Normally I apply the thermal paste to the CPU but when I moved the heat sink around it got messy and I cleaned it all off, but I'll reapply it before replacing the heat sink.

**UPDATE**: it must be something else.

- all 4 pins clicked in
- the thermal paste on the CPU had been
  smeared around so the heat sink had made contact

[image: bottom of heat sink]
[image: side of heat sink]
[image: another side image of heat sink]
[image: top of heat sink]
[image: mother board]

I know the heat sink isn't sitting on properly because when I turn on the computer I get a CPU overheat error (and have to turn off). Is there anything else I can try or should know before buying a new heat sink? The fan works fine so it's only a problem with the connectors.

Comment: If you feel you would have better luck with an after market heatsink you should indeed try one.  Its not clear what you want from us.

Comment: And you need the thermal paste ...

Comment: @Ramhound is that a possible solution? If a heat sink that doesn't fit (and it did before) buying a new one could help?

Comment: I suspect your just installing it wrong but the stock Intel heatsinks are not easy to install in the first place.  How easy an aftermarket one is to install really depends on the brand.

Comment: You may need to squeeze the lower end of the pushpins a little to make them fit through the holes again. Use some pliers, but don’t apply too much presure. Also make sure the pushable thingy is completely retracted.

Comment: @DanielB I pushed on them hard with my thumb. How do I know if I'm pushing too hard?

Comment: There's one pin that never goes in, even if it's the first one. I've got the rest in.

Comment: @Ramhound which brands are easy to install?

Comment: @Celeritas You should do some research and base your purchase on it.

Comment: It's got to be something else. 1) I heard all 4 pins click in 2) the thermal paste on the CPU had been smeared around so I know the heat sink had made contact

Comment: I tried a new CPU fan and it's still the same problem. I notice the light on the motherboard near MemOK is solid red for a second when the computer first turns on. Not sure if it's relevant but the fan spins backwards, then forwards, then stops, then spins forwards again when the computer is first turned on. Could it be a problem with the power connector ?

Comment: What does the power connector have to do with securing the heatsink to the motherboard?

Comment: @Ramhound maybe nothing, that's my question. Does it matter where on the motherboard I attach the CPU fan to get its power? I don't know the terminology, what do you call the little port where you plug in the fan to get the power?

Comment: Fixed it. I didn't think it made a difference where the fan was plugged in as long as it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I see all these posts about this issue and no one has mentioned this... the reason why the translucent pegs are not going to go into the mobo holes is very simple!!!
'Solution'
Look at the translucent peg and inside these pegs is a little black pin, they are used to lock the cooler pegs to the motherboard, the problem is they sometimes get stuck in lock position when you take the cooler fan off. Just your thumbnail is enough to push them back into the translucent peg (3.5mm) and this releases the lockout position. Now the translucent pegs  will fit in the hole and when you turn the translucent peg to lock position the little black pin forces the translucent peg to widen its grip on the hole in the motherboard. Ok rule of thumb...nothing should be forced when fitting any peripheral to a motherboard, if it doesn't fit its the wrong part!!!.

Comment: This helped me, absolute genius. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

make sure they are pointed out when installing.  pop each pin in a diagonal fashion to ensure that one side isn't completely seated before the other.  if you cannot get it with the board installed in the case.  pull the board and then try on a plastic surface, preferably using the esd bag the board came in underneath to prevent static discharge.

once you hear the pins pop into place you can check that they are indeed popped in by flipping the board over you should see the white plastic pins spread out with the black plastic pin popped through the hole pushing them apart.  if that seems unclear I found this video that will help you visually.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcQgZX-4W0o

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible that you aren't pushing hard enough. Sometimes this takes more pressure than people expect. I would suggest supporting the back of the motherboard while trying to stick it in. You may also find it useful to point a camera at that pins when you attempt the install so that you can look at the problem from an angle you might otherwise be unable to see from.

Comment: it's the pin nearest the middle of the motherboard that won't go in

Comment: If that's the case, I would suggest supporting the back of the motherboard while trying to stick it in. You may also find it useful to point a camera at that pin when you attempt the install so that you can look at the problem from an angle you might otherwise be unable to see from.

Comment: @Burgi good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but the problem with these is that after they've been used for a few years the plastic changes shape, and the part that goes through the hole is bent outward making it bigger than the holes. You need to order new ones. They're cheap, but it's also frustrating dealing with this issue if you ever take the heatsink off again.

I'd recommend just buying a cheap third party heatsink with actual screws to avoid the issue in the future.